# Trigonometric equation $\tan(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2})=-\sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to solve a trigonometric equation below:

$$\tan(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2})=-\sqrt{3}$$

What is the value of $x$ for $x>0$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: First, what is the angle $\theta$ such that $\tan(\theta)=-\sqrt3$ ?

Comment: lets simplify the problem a bit. Suppose $\tan\theta=\sqrt{3}$. Lets build a triangle with the opposite side$=\sqrt{3}$ and the adjacent side $=1$ (e.g. $\tan\theta = \frac{opposite}{adjacent}$). What would the hypotenuse be? Does this triangle look familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\tan a=b$ iff $a=\arctan b+k\pi$, for $k \in \Bbb Z$.

And $\arctan -\sqrt{3}=-\arctan\sqrt{3}=-\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Hence

$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi\right)$$

If you want all values of $x>0$, then simply take $k>0$. The smallest positive value is

$$x_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note $\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-\sqrt{3}$, and $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$, so this means that for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}=n\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}\implies x=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\left(n-\frac{1}{3}\right).$$

Since we require $x>0$, this is equivalent to saying $n-\frac{1}{3}>0$, and since $n$ is an integer, we must have $n>0$. So in conclusion all possible solutions are of the form:

$$x=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\left(n-\frac{1}{3}\right),\quad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$